# cannot find symbol length (Java)

Tags: java

Given an array of numbers, I have to return the number of times that 9 appears in the array. I created a new array, where I added all the 9s from the original array. But at the end when I want to return the length of the new array, I get an error "cannot find symbol length".
I know that in this case, length is an attribute, not a method, so that's not the problem. I even used the length attribute in the for loop and it doesn't seem to be a problem (because the error occurs at line 8). This is starting to become frustrating. If anyone knows what the reason for this is, please let me know.

```
public int arrayCount9(int[] nums) {
    ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++){
        if (nums[i] == 9){
            array.add(nums[i]);
        }
    }
    int len = array.length;
    return len;
}
```

Comment: `ArrayList` isn't an array. And why do you add all 9's to a list? Just count them...

Comment: What is nums???

Comment: @Pavlo read the method parameter. It's an `int[]`

Comment: @QBrute Oh i see, just looked at the code area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `ArrayList<Integer>` isn't the same as an `Integer[]` but you're using the same variable as in an array to get the size of the list.

An `ArrayList<Integer>` has a method called `ArrayList#size()` instead of a variable called `length` to get the size of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the method size() for collection class ArrayList.